# Why does it start previous android application?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working in eclipse and i have gone through Hello world and LinearLayout but when i start the second one, awd opens Hello world first and than it goes to the second app.

I don't know what do i have to set up to run only chosen app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to manually kill the previous process running in the emulator (and/or the device) ... you can do so via the [DDMS perspective](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html).

Answer (score 0):

when you run the Hello World application and if you don't back to the home screen using back button that means your still running this application and when you start another application from eclipse your current application goes in background with pause mode so every time whenever you change in another appl and again run you first see the hello world application.

it will maintain the stack of all the activity.